# why is MySQL select date not working for different month

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, date

I have a very old database I made when I was still learning PHP and MySQL.
If I populate:

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE (date BETWEEN 'Aug.01 2016' AND 'Aug.31 2016')
```

I can actually populate rows

`Found rows: 4  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec.`

But once I change my month (moving the range from Aug 1 to July 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE (date BETWEEN 'Jul.01 2016' AND 'Aug.31 2016')
```

I got nothing even so the range July 1 ~ Aug 31 includes Aug 1 ~ Aug 31 (from previous example), which should populate at least 4 rows

`Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.016 sec.`

Is there a way I can populate the rows even they have different month?

Comment: What data type is `date`? Is it `DATETIME` or is it just a string?

Comment: @Machavity it is `VARCHAR` so format is actually a string something like `Jul.01 2016`

Comment: You need to consider a switch to a `DATETIME` then. Doing index lookups on a date like that will be expensive

Comment: store dates in a database as proper [date types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html), this will make life a million times easier

Comment: @Dagon I'll bid a million +1

Comment: so, it seems like I need to make a new table with `DATETIME` and regenerate proper values... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first convert your date string to a valid date:

```
SET @date := 'Aug.01 2016';

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%M.%d %Y');
```

**Output(yyyy-mm-dd):** `2016-08-01`

Now use this in your query to search for result having dates between `2016-07-01 & 2016-08-31`.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Jobs 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%M.%d %Y') BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-08-31';
```

**Note:** But date should be stored in a `date` datatype column. It's high time you converted the `datatype` to `date` of your `date` column.

In order to do that follow the steps below:

```
ALTER TABLE Jobs
ADD new_date_column date;

UPDATE Jobs 
SET new_date_column = STR_TO_DATE(date,'%M.%d %Y');

ALTER TABLE Jobs DROP COLUMN `date`;

ALTER TABLE Jobs CHANGE COLUMN `new_date_column` `date` date;
```

**Steps in a nut shell:**

1. Add a new column in `Jobs` table of type `date`.
2. Now update this new column with the values from your `date` column
       after converting to a valid date.
3. You don't need that `date` column. So drop it.
4. Now rename the newly created column to `date`.